# How to resolve Apache Ignite with Hibernate dependencies?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, ignite

I want to integrate hibernate in Apache Ignite. I know that hibernate is a lgpl dependency. (Even I don't know how to use lgpl dependencies).

> ....@ubuntu:~.../apache-ignite-2.5.0-src/modules/hibernate-5.1$ mvn clean package -DskipTests -Prelease,lgpl

After all I have seen "BUILD SUCCESS" message. Now, when I look at the `.../apache-ignite-2.5.0-src/modules/hibernate-5.1` directory, I see that there are

- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar and
- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.sources.jar

Additionally in this directory `.../.m2/repository/org/apache/ignite/ignite-hibernate_5.1/2.5.0`

I have these files:

- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar
- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.pom.lastUpdated
- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar.lastUpdated
- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0-sources.jar.lastUpdated
- ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.pom
- _remote.repositories

Now, what I want instead: to just create a lib folder in my project and add to **correct jar or whatever it is** hibernate lpgl dependency, then right click the project->properties->Java Build Path->Add JARS, then i will choose the file in the lib folder.

I have used hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar and hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.sources.jar in the `apache-ignite-2.5.0-src/modules/hibernate-5.1`, but it didn't work.

I have also used `ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar` in the `.m2/repository/org/apache`, but it didn't work either.

(In both, I have copied the files and copied to lib as I said)

What should i do?

UPDATED:
So far what i did:
- I have take the jars from my local repository and put to the src -> main -> resources -> lib. (Here is the picture [lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC4yp.png) )
- Then go to Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + (add the lib folder) (Here is the picture [projectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHiPJ.png))
- Now, my project works well when i work on ide or using onejar plugin.
- But when i want to convert to jar via maven-shade plugin, it gives an error. [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VzHD.png)
- Here is the maven-shaded plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>ignite.IgniteMainApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

- Here is the one jar [plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzOBT.png)
- How do solve the problem in maven-shaded ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: thanks, hope it will be easy to understand now.

Comment: If you're doing anything of scale, you probably don't want hibernate in the mix, and will quickly join the ranks of those who tear out hibernate because it introduces more issues than it resolves. In my experience, hibernate is good for rapid prototyping and proof of concept, but is quickly chokes on anything of scale.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify what exactly didn't work for you, but I would assume that you're missing required dependencies (Hibernate JARs, etc.). The easiest way it to use Maven that would fetch all those dependencies automatically. Alternatively, you can build full package as described in `DEVNOTES.txt` file. You will then find all the modules with all the dependencies under `libs` folder.

Comment: my problem is that i can not add the ignite-hibernate_5.1 dependency in my project. In particular, i want to put ignite-hibernate_5.1 jar to my lib folder in the project then add it to classpath. However which jar file should i use?

Comment: Well, `ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar` is the one that contains Ignite integration code, but it has dependencies that are also required. Please update your question with a description of the actual issue. It's absolutely not clear what you're fighting with.

Comment: I just want to know how to add `ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar` this dependency in my project. Because, documentation in Ignite is not clear for me? Could you provide step by step. (But please think of it, these project will be deployed server's machine not only local at the end)

Comment: I can do configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml, vs..). I just need to understand how can i get `ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar` this one.

Comment: The way how to add a JAR to your project depends only on how your project is organized, it's not related to Ignite itself. You can use Maven, Gradle, add JARs manually, etc. If you need help with this, you should describe your issue in more detail - what exactly you're doing, what you get as a result (any errors?), etc. Otherwise it's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: The Gradle dependency is not downloading this jar, if somebody knows please let me also know what to do ,to download this jar via gradle 
Exception:
Could not find org.apache.ignite:ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a jar in IDEA and expect maven to see it. These are two separate tools. For maven to work correctly you need to have all dependencies in the maven repository.

When building `ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.5.0.jar` with maven use `install` command. It will add the jar to your local maven repository, and it will be available to your project as a maven dependency. After that add a dependency in the maven config (via `<dependency>` tag) and remove the jar from your libs directory - you don't need it, maven won't be able to use it, and having it will only cause problems.